# How does one use the --keep and --ignore features of vowpal wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

The documentation merely mentions that these features exist, but there is no example code that I can find.

I currently have data of the form

```
1 '0001 |11 x:0.3
0 '0002 |11 x:0.8
1 '0003 |11 x:0.3
0 '0004 |11 x:0.9
1 '0005 |11 x:0.2
```

thus I have one namespace called 11 in the file train.vw

I give the command

```
vw train.vw --keep 11 -c -k --passes 40 -l 0.85 -f model.vw --loss_function quantile --quantile_tau 0.6
```

and get the error

```
vw: the argument ('11') for option '--keep' is invalid
```

it works fine without keep,

```
vw train.vw -c -k --passes 40 -l 0.85 -f model.vw --loss_function quantile --quantile_tau 0.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this should be better documented...

The arguments to options that deal with name-spaces, refer to those name-spaces by their 1st letter only.  This is a limitation stemming from the way name spaces are currenty implemented for the purpose of crossing, keeping and ignoring, as a fast look-up table indexed by the 1st letter.

So in this particular case, you should use `--keep 1` rather than `--keep 11`.

Similarly, for crossing features, e.g. `-q AB` the `A` and the `B` refer to the first letter of the name-spaces you want to cross, respectively.

Comment: So can I use an extended alphabet to have a large number of namespaces and is it case sensitive?  So 0-9a-zA-Z - gives 64, are only alphanumeric of ascii usable or the complete UTF-8 or any non punctuation or control character (À, Ä, etc.)  http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024 ? Or could say use Chinese and/or other languages that would give me a lot more namespaces.

Comment: According to the source, the lookup table is a `vector<unsigned char>` so the subset of UTF-8 representable by one byte and no prefixes should work (255 different possible values, I believe). HTH.